# SCSS Error: File to import not found or unreadable

Tags: sass, npm, webpack, css-loader

I upgraded sass-loader from 0.2 to 3.2.0 and node from 0.10.35 to 5.0.0 Everything was working fine with node 0.10.35 and sass-loader 0.2. But now I am getting following error while importing scss file.

```
ERROR in ./app/lib/mob/styles/modules/_template-layout.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: 
@import "../../styles/functions/common-functions",
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: ../../views/mixins
Parent style sheet: stdin
```

Webpack config file:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded") },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader") }
        ]
    },
```

Import statements are in 12cc-store/app/lib/mob/styles/modules/_template-layout.scss file:

```
@import "../../styles/functions/common-functions",
        "../../views/mixins",
        "../../styles/mixins/media-query-mixins";
```

and 12cc-store/app/lib/mob/styles/functions/_common-functions.scss is absolute file path

Don't know what I am missing. I tried with absolute path, require() statement instead of @import but still no luck. I found one thread saying downgrade node version, but that is what i want to do. I want to update node and all node modules. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is dir structure?

Comment: @pradeep1991singh i updated the question with file path

Comment: Be sure that `12cc-store/app/lib/mob/views/mixins.scss` is exists.

Comment: @BobSponge all files and paths are correct. am getting error for all @ import statements. Something changed with latest versions. I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Scss file names starts with "_" symbol? Files are [resolved](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader#imports)  by webpack, not scss compiler, so it is incorrect for webpack.

Comment: You also need to add `['.scss']` to `resolve.extensions` [section](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions) in your webpack config.

Comment: @BobSponge i tried with _ and .scss extenstion also. Its not working and in webpack also I am having resolver for all libPath.